# Can't use application permissions (roles) to access Microsoft Graph API group calendar

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

My goal is to list the calendar events of an Office 365 group using the Microsoft Graph API.
The endpoint used is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/events` [based on the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_events).  Using the Graph Explorer, I'm able to get the information with my delegated permissions.  The problem is when I make the same call using application permissions.  I'm positive JWT token contains the required roles to make the call (Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All) but I'm getting the following error:

> Access is denied. Check credentials and try again

Curiously enough, I'm able to get the group `/v1.0/groups/{id}` but whatever is related to it's calendar and events isn't accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Using application permissions to look at group resources/contents is not currently supported. Please see known issues here:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#groups-and-microsoft-teams.

If this is required for your scenarios, please vote for

- https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18747862-app-authentication-to-retrieve-conversation-messag or
- https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16851937-allow-application-only-consent-to-read-conversation

Both of which are about app-only access to group conversations (similar to group events).

Otherwise please create a new user voice request.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the insight.  It's confusing since the API documentation clearly states that you can use the Application permission type with Group.Read.All or Group.ReadWrite.All.
I hadn't seen the "known issues" page.  I guess all I can do is vote for the related issues on user voice! thanks

Comment: Many apologies.  I just checked the topics on group events and can see why you thought this was supported.  This needs to be fixed.  It even *suggests* that groups are supported with a Personal account which is also wrong.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the follow up.  Glad that you can clear up the documentation for the benefit of everyone.